# tengo una tabla personalizada en wordpress,no agrega un nuevo campo a la tabla segun la version

Tags: wordpress, tabla-dinámica

les explico:
hay una pagina que tiene un formulario al momento de cargar cualquier pagina, este script php se ejecuta y crea una tabla wp_reservaciones en la bd. pero si se vuelve a refrescar cualquier pagina muestra este mensaje, creo que lo unico bueno es el formulario que  guarda bien la informacion en la tabla.

```
Error en la base de datos de WordPress: [Table 'wp_reservaciones' already exists]
CREATE TABLE wp_reservaciones( id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
 fecha datetime NOT NULL,
 correo varchar(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
 telefono varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 mensaje longtext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id) )DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
```

en el config de wordpress tengo habilitado 
para los mensje de eror que tira.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

que deberia hacer:
si mas adelante se quiere agregar un nuevo campo a la tabla por ejemplo telefono2 solo tendria que agregarle en ese script el nuevo campo y cambiar la version que esta al inicio del codigo.
al momento de refrescar cualquier pagina donde estemos. el escrip compara las versiones y hace la actualizacion agregando ese campo.

no se donde esta el problema del porque no lo hace.

les dejo los script desde donde se hace el llamado desde el functions y el resto

function

```
//tabla personalizadas y otras funciones
require( get_template_directory() . '/inc/database.php');
//funciones para la reservacinoes
require( get_template_directory() . '/inc/reservaciones.php');
```

basededatos.php
le coloque version 0.2 asi cuando se refresque la pagina agregue el nuevo campo a la tabla
supuestamente

```
<?php
function elcomedor_database(){

    //wpdb obtenemos los metodos para trabajar con la tabla
    global $wpdb;
    //agregamos una version
    global $treserva_dbversion;
    $treserva_dbversion="0.2";

    //obtener el prefijo
    $tabla = $wpdb->prefix. 'reservaciones';

    $charset_collate= $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    //creamos la tabla
    $sql="CREATE TABLE $tabla(
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            fecha datetime NOT NULL,
            correo varchar(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
            telefono varchar(10) NOT NULL,
            mensaje longtext NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )$charset_collate;";

//dbDelta para ejecutar el sql y esta es la direccion
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);

//se agrega la versino de la bd para compararla  con fuuras actulizaciones  
    add_option('treserva_dbversion', $treserva_dbversion);

//obtener version 
$version_actual=get_option('treserva_dbversion');

//aqui actualizar campos de la tabla. 

//comparamos las 2 versiones
if($treserva_dbversion != $version_actual){
    $tabla = $wpdb->prefix. 'reservaciones';

    //agregar o quitar campos a la tabla
    $sql="CREATE TABLE $tabla(
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        fecha datetime NOT NULL,
        correo varchar(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        telefono varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        telefono2 varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        mensaje longtext NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);

    //actualiza la version actual en caso de que alla
    update_option('treserva_dbversion', $treserva_dbversion);
    }
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'elcomedor_database');

//funcion para comprobar si la version instalada es igual a la bd nueva
function elcomedor_db_revisar(){
    global $treserva_dbversion;
    if(get_site_option('treserva_dbversion') != $treserva_dbversion)
    {
        elcomedor_database();
    }
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'elcomedor_db_revisar');
?>
```

reservaciones.php

```
<?php

function lapizzeria_guardar(){
    global $wpdb;

if (isset($_POST['enviar']) && isset($_POST['oculto'])=="1"):

        $nombre= sanitize_text_field($_POST['nombre']);
        $fecha= sanitize_text_field($_POST['fecha']);
        $correo= sanitize_text_field($_POST['correo']);
        $telefono= sanitize_text_field($_POST['telefono']);
        $mensaje= sanitize_text_field($_POST['mensaje']);


        $tabla=$wpdb->prefix . "reservaciones";

        $datos=array(
            'nombre'=> $nombre,
            'fecha'=> $fecha,
            'correo'=> $correo,
            'telefono'=> $telefono,
            'mensaje'=> $mensaje
            );

        //EL FORMATO ES PARA DECIRLE QUE ES LO QUE ESTA GUARDANDO EN LA BASE DE DATOS EN NUESTRO CADO SERIA STRING %s

        $formato=array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s'
            );

        $wpdb->insert($tabla,$datos,$formato);

        $url=get_page_by_title('Gracias por su reserva');
        wp_redirect(get_permalink($url->ID));
        exit();
    endif;

}
add_action('init','lapizzeria_guardar'); 
?>
```

formulario.php

```
<form class="reserva-contacto" method="post">
            <h2>Realiza una reservación</h2>
                <div class="campo">
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                </div>

                <div class="campo">
                    <input name="fecha" placeholder="Fecha" required>
                </div>

                <div class="campo">
                    <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="Correo" required>
                </div>

                <div class="campo">
                    <input type="tel" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" required>
                </div>

                <div class="campo">
                    <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" name="enviar" class="boton">
                <input type="hidden" name="oculto" value="1">
</form>
```

espero me puedan hechar una mano, aver donde tengo los errores
saludos

Answer (score 0):

El error que te está enseñando es debido a que la tabla ya se encuentra creada entonces cuando le indicas en el php que cree esa tabla te devuelve un error.

Para evitar ese comportamiento hay en SQL una forma de comprobar si la tabla existe, en el caso de existir no ejecuta el create, y en el caso de no existir crea la tabla.

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tabla(
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        fecha datetime NOT NULL,
        correo varchar(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        telefono varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        mensaje longtext NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)$charset_collate;";
```

Comment: Saudos [KraakoV]. tienes toda la razon realize el cambio. me surge otra duda: si la table no existe la crea

Comment: Saudos [KraakoV]. tienes toda la razon realize el cambio. y todo bien si la table no existe la crea y si existe pasa al siguiente codigo: hice un cambio hace la comprobacion de las versiones `if($treserva_dbversion != $version_actual){ ` si son diferente entonces pasa al siguiente codigo `$sql="ALTER TABLE $tabla ADD $nuevocampo varchar(50) AFTER telefono";` **aclaro** todo lo esta haciendo no manda ningun mensaje de error y la verificacion la hago en el sentido que estan llegando las variables con el **pre** y  `**var_dump() de php**` pero en la bd no creo el campo nuevo.